# OpenWRT - Manage Virtual LAN

Tags: router, vlan, openwrt, coovachilli

I have an `Ubiquiti AirRouter` with **OpenWRT** on it and I've been trying to separate the manage of the ports.

I've formated the router using `CoovaChilli` app, anyways the app just help to install OpenWRT on the router and gives an easy UI-WEB manager.

The router has internal programmable switch, and as far as I understand it is possible to separate the LAN PORTS.

I've tried to configure `/etc/config/network`  following [OpenWRT - Switch Documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network/switch)

- In my Ubiquiti router it seems `eth0` and `eth1` are different from the tutorial. In the tutorial the switch is `eth0` in my router it is `eth1`
- I have the basic configuration and I'd like to modify it, right now 4 ethernet ports have access to internet and are managed by default configuration.
- I'd like to have 2 ports (1 and 2) with default configuration (Internet access), and the other 2 ports (3 and 4) redirected to a Hotspot

I need to have 2 different "devices" to do this, e.g. I need **br-lan0** to be the defaults ports and **br-hot0** the redirected ports.

I tried 1 million ways and everytime I try a configuration, the router stopped to assign IP's and I don't know what's happening or how to fix it.

This is an example configuration I've tried:

```
config 'interface' 'lan'
    option 'ifname' 'eth1.0'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'ipaddr' '192.168.1.1'
    option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
    option 'defaultroute' '0'
    option 'peerdns' '0'
    option 'nat'    '1'

config 'interface' 'hot'
    option 'ifname'  'eth1.1'
    option 'proto'   'dhcp'
```

---

Some technical information for Airrouter & OpenWRT can be found [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/ubiquiti/airrouter)

Comment: Have you made sure to power cycle your router after saving each new configuration to try, just in case? On some devices there have been reports that the switch doesn't properly reset when rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to accompany your plain network config with the corresponding switch configuration.

Also, do not use VLAN 0, as this is a special VLAN.

Try something along the lines of this:

```
config 'interface' 'lan'
    option 'ifname' 'eth1.1'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'ipaddr' '192.168.1.1'
    option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
    option 'defaultroute' '0'
    option 'peerdns' '0'
    option 'nat'    '1'

config 'interface' 'hot'
    option 'ifname'  'eth1.2'
    option 'proto'   'dhcp'

config 'switch'
    option 'name'    'switch0'
    option 'enable'  '1'
    option 'enable_vlan' '1'
    option 'reset'   '1'

config 'switch_vlan'
    option 'vlan'    '1'
    option 'device'  'switch0'
    option 'ports'   '0t 1 2'

config 'switch_vlan'
    option 'vlan'    '2'
    option 'device'  'switch0'
    option 'ports'   '0t 3 4'
```

Also, are you absolutely sure that the switch is internally `eth1`?

Reading through the relevant architecture files in the OpenWRT distribution shows me that most `ar71xx` devices have their switch on `eth0`, including the airrouter.

Here's the relevant section from `base-files/etc/uci-defaults/02_network`:

```
ap121 |\
ap121-mini |\
ap96 |\
airrouter |\
dir-600-a1 |\
dir-615-c1 |\
dir-615-e4 |\
ja76pf |\
mynet-n600 |\
oolite |\
rb-750 |\
rb-751 |\
tew-632brp |\
tew-712br |\
tl-mr3220 |\
tl-mr3220-v2 |\
tl-mr3420 |\
tl-wdr3500 |\
tl-wr741nd |\
tl-wr741nd-v4 |\
tl-wr841n-v7 |\
tl-wr841n-v9 |\
whr-g301n |\
whr-hp-g300n |\
whr-hp-gn |\
wzr-hp-ag300h)
        ucidef_set_interfaces_lan_wan "eth0" "eth1"
        ucidef_add_switch "switch0" "1" "1"
        ucidef_add_switch_vlan "switch0" "1" "0 1 2 3 4"
        ;;
```

Note the `ucidef_set_interfaces_lan_wan` line that lists `eth0` before `eth1`, which designates `eth0` as LAN nic and `eth1` as WAN nic.

EDIT:

(in which case you would replace `eth1` by `eth0` in the above config and replace `eth0` by `eth1`, if you have that somewhere else in your config)